# Can we access the variable and methods of class A in class B without extends keyword

Tags: java

Can we access the variable and methods of class A in class B without extends class A to class B

```
without using

public class A
{

    //body of the class
}

public class B extends A
{

}
```

Comment: Needs more context. Are you asking for the `public` keyword (which without even more context is probably a bad idea)?

Answer (score 6):

Create a new Object of class `A` in class `B` and access its methods / variables.

```
class B {

    A a = new A();

    void bMethod() {
        a.aMethod();
    }
}

class A {

    void aMethod() {    
    }
}
```